# Want to match and count whole text or words of dictionary with search text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, text

I have 2 files one is .txt file which contains countries name and other is csv file which contain the detail (text). I want to match the country names row by row from text csv file and count and print that matched words

I have try this code:

```
#NEW!
import csv
import time

#OLD! Import the keywords
f = open('country names.txt', 'r')
allKeywords = f.read().lower().split("\n")
f.close()


#CHANGED! Import the 'Details' column from the CSV file
allTexts = []
fullRow = []
with open('Detail_file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        #the full row for each entry, which will be used to recreate the improved CSV file in a moment
        fullRow.append((row['sr. no.'], row['Details'], row['LOC']))

        #the column we want to parse for our keywords
        row = row['Details'].lower()
        allTexts.append(row)

#NEW! a flag used to keep track of which row is being printed to the CSV file   
counter = 0

#NEW! use the current date and time to create a unique output filename
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-(%H-%M-%S)")
filename = 'output-' + str(timestr) + '.csv'

#NEW! Open the new output CSV file to append ('a') rows one at a time.
with open(filename, 'a') as csvfile:

    #NEW! define the column headers and write them to the new file
    fieldnames = ['sr. no.', 'Details', 'LOC', 'Placename']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    #NEW! define the output for each row and then print to the output csv file
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    #OLD! this is the same as before, for currentRow in fullRow:
    for entry in allTexts:

        matches = 0
        storedMatches = []

        #for each entry:
        allWords = entry.split(' ')
        for words in allWords:


            #if a keyword match is found, store the result.
            if words in allKeywords:
                if words in storedMatches:
                    continue
                else:
                    storedMatches.append(words)
                matches += 1

        #CHANGED! send any matches to a new row of the csv file.
        if matches == 0:
            newRow = fullRow[counter]
        else:
            matchTuple = tuple(storedMatches)
            newRow = fullRow[counter] + matchTuple

        #NEW! write the result of each row to the csv file
        writer.writerows([newRow])
        counter += 1
```

its work good and its output is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnEuB.jpg)

so I have a problem that if my dictionary keyword(country name) contains a single word e.g. Australia, America etc its work good BUT

if my dictionary any keyword contain more then 1 words e.g. New Zealand ,South Africa etc its not match and not count so I have this problem because the above code is working on word by word matching, so how to solve this problem if my dictionary any keyword contain more then 1 word like conatins 2, 3, 4, .... words .
and where we will add solution code in the above code.

One logic is in my mind 
if any keyword contain more then one word then during searching if ist word of that specific keyword match then code check the next word from search text according to the keyword words if match then ok otherwise continue to the next keyword.

Comment: Is this an excel issue?

Comment: @SolarMike   okay, It was my mistake.

Comment: Just that in excel I would think of joining words together  ("south"&" "&"africa") then doing the search...

Comment: Can you give a sample of the input files and the expected output?

Comment: @EvensF Yes sure, where should I send you file and expected output ?

Comment: @csit: The same way you have included in your question the text of your code, edit your question to include the text of the other files. CSV files are text files that you can copy in your question.

Comment: I would suggest to do the key word search vice versa: iterate over the keywords and see if one is in the entire text.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't easy to grasp what you were trying to do. And I'm not sure you understand what a CSV file is. Try to open it in the same editor (**not** Excel) you are editing your Python script.

Anyway, here's my attempt:

```
import csv
import time

with open('country names.txt', 'r') as f:
    all_keywords = list(line.lower().rstrip("\n") for line in f)

with open('Detail_file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    full_rows = [(row['sr. no.'], row['Details'], row['LOC']) for row in reader]

time_string = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-(%H-%M-%S)")
filename = 'output-' + time_string + '.csv'

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['sr. no.', 'Details', 'LOC', 'Placename'])

    for input_row in full_rows:
        stored_matches_unique = set(x for x in all_keywords if x in input_row[1].lower())
        stored_matches = list(stored_matches_unique)
        new_row = input_row + stored_matches
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```